# Android app - call google cloud endpoint - custom data type input parameter

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a google cloud endpoint which adds users data to the table on mysql google cloud. I am calling this endpoint from my android app. I am passing user's data to the endpoint in the form of `User` object(custom data type created by me). The request hits the service but the values inside the object are null. I mean to say that on the server side `userDetails.getUserId()` , `userDetails.getUserEmail()` and `userDetails.getUserName()` are all NULLS.
The code of my endpoint is given below:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "addUser")
public UserResponse addUser(User userDetails) {
    UserResponse response = new UserResponse();
    String query = "{ call myDbName.mySPName(?,?,?) }";
    ResultSet rs;

    try{
    String url = null;
    if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
        // Connecting from App Engine.
        // Load the class that provides the "jdbc:google:mysql://"
        // prefix.
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
            url ="jdbc:google:mysql://my-project-name:myDbName?user=root";
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){}
    } else {
        // Connecting from an external network.
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql-google-cloud-ip:3306?user=root";
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){}
    }
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

         CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
        stmt.setString(1, userDetails.getUserId());
        stmt.setString(2, userDetails.getUserEmail());
        stmt.setString(3, userDetails.getUserName());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        response.setResult(1);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        response.setResult(0);
        log.severe(ex.getMessage()+ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Please let me know how to fix this. I have read it somewhere that only primitive data types are supported by cloud endpoint. I do have some endpoint which require vast amount of data in the form of nested complex objects where I cannot rely on just primitive data types.

**EDIT**

Import section of my endpoint looks like:

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;

import javax.inject.Named;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
```

Comment: Based on my personal experience I would avoid Endpoints for what you are trying to do. From what I have seen Endpoints is very buggy and does not scale when you get fancy with complex data types, etc. There are defects filed against it for basic functionality that never seem to get fixed. Worse than that, from my experience, even years after Endpoints was introduced, new defects in basic functionality are found. Add to that uninformed design choices. I have found Endpoints to be poorly designed, poorly tested, poorly documented, and would avoid it if possible. Just looks good on paper.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any alternative? I want to use web services to  interact with my database from my android app.

Comment: What if you use API Explorer to make the request? And what do you define as a primitive data type? Endpoints supports object types, which in the Java sense of the word is not primitive. @Uli, I'd love to hear if there were outstanding bugs that you came across on the public tracker that needed fixing. We are open source now and working on making the framework reliable.

Comment: It works if I use API explorer. By primitive I meant integer/String/long,etc.

Comment: @sair: Please let me know what could be the probable reasons behind this behavior? Everything works when I use Android Studio to run app on my mobile. But when I download the app from play store as a beta tester the request I send contains null values on the server side.

Comment: @saiyr Seeing that my most aggravating outstanding defect got closed as we speak (thank you!) for Endpoints v2, maybe things are improving. v2 is brand-new & beta, though, and it does not have Android Studio integration yet, so I will wait for robustness. It will take time for my burns to heal. Perhaps v2 will fix the random 500 errors from the web server, too?! (I have been too resigned about Endpoints to consult the defect tracker for this)

Comment: @gliese581g You can use your own JSON or XML marshaling (there are many libraries for that), which has the added advantage that you are not locked into a proprietary technology. In hindsight I wish I had done that. I was lured in by the Android Studio integration, but instead wasted a lot of time troubleshooting Endpoints bugs. I have my doubts about plain App Engine, too, though.

Comment: When you run using Android Studio, are you hitting the local dev server or a deployed app? It's possible there's some weird difference going on between local dev server and the deployed app. @Uli the 500 errors _should_ be solved. v2 was a pretty large architectural refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste imports, but I'm guessing that user class in your code is part of GAE api: [User class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User)
To confirm it please check your imports. I would suggest also to rename your own User class to something more specific ex. `UserTransport`.

Comment: It works when I run it on my mobile from Android Studio. But when I download it from Google Play Store as a Beta Tester it gets null values on the server side. I am completely clueless about it.

Comment: Are you using authentication? If yes - difference can be in certificates.

Comment: I am using in-build Google Sing-in(GoogleSignInApi) for android app. But nothing for cloud endpoints.